# FTP mkdir function

Tags: php, ftp

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .I have tried all possible paths!

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$name=strtolower($name);
if (is_dir("./Abhishek/Project/events/$name"))
{

echo 'Event Already Present';
}
else
{
 mkdir("./Abhishek/Project/events/$name"); 
 include './upload/fileupload1.php';
 echo "Event Successfully Created";
```

}
?>

i have uploaded all my files on FTP. ON Local host every thin works fine As usual but when i tried on live server,FTP directory did not create..do i have to use ftp_mkdir? i have never used it .

Comment: Did you check all the remote permissions?

Comment: do i have to enable write 'world' permission ??